# Is this a good method to initialise fast click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fastclick.js

I am trying to keep my html clean and hence require libraries / plugins via my app.js file where all javascript / jquery logic happens. I am using FastClick library to ommit 300ms tap delay and initialising it this way.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /* Load and initialize FastClick, ommits 300ms tap delay */
    $.getScript('lib/fastclick.js', function () {
        new FastClick(document.body);
    }); /* END FastClick */

}); /* END jQuery */
```

Is this making semantic sense and will it be more harmful using this instead of adding fastclick.js file in html page?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach but, you are waiting till the DOM is ready before downloading the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes semantic sense and judging from the [fastclick docs](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), it doesn't look harmful.

> Include fastclick.js in your JavaScript bundle or add it to your HTML page...

They are saying that it's safe to include it as a concatenated file or as a standalone. You are free to include the FastClick source code however you see fit.

Really their documentation over complicates the initialization of FastClick. The `document.documentElement` property is available the moment JavaScript begins execution, and represents the `<html>` element. This could be used as the root element for FastClick, negating the need for a DOMContentLoaded or domready event handler:

```
new FastClick(document.documentElement);
```

No event handlers needed. Now you can respond to clicks as the page is loading if you want, and before the full HTML document has been parsed.

Edit: @jungy brings up a good point in his comment:

> ... you are waiting till the DOM is ready before downloading the library.

The complete code example:

```
jQuery.getScript("lib/fastclick.js", function() {
    new FastClick(document.documentElement);
});
```